# unable to boot to windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu along side windows 10. When I boot, it loads grub page and I can continue to boot Ubuntu. But if I choose windows boot manager on the grub page to load Windows, I get following error:
[image]

initially I could not figure a way to boot to windows, I clean installed Windows 10, cleaned Ubuntu partition and installed Ubuntu again. However, I still get same message. I noticed that I could boot to windows through BIOS boot media selector (Enter then F12 on my laptop) but not through grub.

Is there an easy fix for it?

Device: Lenovo Carbon X1
Windows: Win 10
Ubuntu: 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command from installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Try going into system setup and there windows boot manager.I got it by doing that but unable to find it in the intitial grub